# How to configure service discovery in aws ecs using the new console

Tags: containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

In the classic AWS console it was possible to configure service discovery.  It looks like this has been dropped in the new console.

How does it then need to be done in the new console?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found out how to switch back to the classic console. It's a switch at the top-left corner. So that's basically the work-around.

Answer (score 0):

We will be adding Service Discovery to the new console - I cannot provide a date yet but it is something we are working on right now.

Meanwhile please switch back to the old console to configure SD. Please do keep those comments/feedback coming!

Comment: I've spent several hours because thought that "Service Connect" is a new name for service discovery, and it's something wrong with my new cluster  It looks almost the same but doesn't create DNS records 

Comment: Sorry about that! Service Connect is brand new  it's much better than Service Discovery - no DNS name shenanigans, automatic load balancing... give it a try! https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-connect.html

Comment: "no DNS name shenanigans" but I need DNS records to connect part of my service in EC2 with ECS. It's difficult to use "Service Connect" because services on EC2 should be reimplemented to use Discovery API instead of internal DNS (if I understood right). And EC2 can host 3rd party software which cannot be modified.

Comment: I see what you mean  yea in that case please use the classic console for now. I will forward your use case to our team and see if there are plans to address that.

Comment: Any update on the option to use DNS as a means for service discovery in AWS?